# Cannot login with WatiN

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer, watin

I'm trying to log in a website that use a ".cgi" instead of a ".html". The input field have this HTML code:

```
<input name="username" class="input" type="text" size="20"></input>
```

As you can see there is nothing special. I got to the website but it doesn't write anything. I did it with a simple case (Google) and it did work.

```
using ( var Browser = new IE())
{
    Browser.GoTo("http://testweb.com"); 
    Browser.TextField(Find.ByName("username")).TypeText("User");
    Browser.TextField(Find.ByName("password")).TypeText("Pass");
}
```

Does anyone knows what's not working ?

**UPDATE:**

**-----------------------**

I've tried this code:

```
using (var Browser = new IE())
{
    Browser.GoTo("testweb.com");

    TextFieldCollection textFields = Browser.TextFields;

    foreach (var field in textFields)
    {
        if (field.Name == "username")
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("FOUND");
        }
    }
}
```

and I obtain this:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Comment: i am not sure if any website which allows to login without submitting login form.

Comment: That's not the point (actually I already knows that I've not submitted the login form), the point is that I can't even type the username

Comment: This seems to be exactly the same question you asked yesterday - with a little bit of info added - you really should have edited that question.

Comment: I wanted to delete the previous one but I don't know how

Comment: All you needed to do was edit it to add the extra info.

Comment: As a suggestion you could check if the text field exists or if the name is different to what you expect - see the answer here for checking the TextFields : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965524/login-in-a-webpage-with-watin

Comment: I've already tried this solution and it didn't work. However, I have the same script in Python and it works. I've noticed that If I put an instruction after the line "Browser.TextField(Find.ByName("username")).TypeText("User");" it never arrive to do it.

Comment: Did you find the "username" TextField in the collection?

Comment: Nope, it didn't find it

Comment: In that case why did you try to write to it? See this as a better technique - you check if the field exists first : http://www.michalsporek.com/blog/index.php/posts/browser-automation-with-watin-and-c-net

Comment: Information added. I've have already tried to write but it doesn't work.